# How to replace multiple tabs with a single comma in a file using C#

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to create a CSV from a .txt file. The file contains tab delimited data but in some cases has multiple tabs. I am currently able to handle a single tab to comma conversion but when I run into the multiple tabs I am replacing it with multiple commas which messes up the spreadsheet down the road. Here is my current code:

```
private void ConvertToCSV(ListBox listBox)
        {
            string txtpath = DIRPATH + listBoxFiles.SelectedItem + ".txt";
            string csvpath = DIRPATH + listBoxFiles.SelectedItem + ".csv";

            // Read through rows in the text file and replace tabs with 
            // commas

            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtpath);
            var csv = lines.Select(row => string.Join(",", row.Split('\t')));

            // Replace the .txt extention with .csv

            File.WriteAllLines(txtpath, csv);
            System.IO.File.Move(txtpath, csvpath);

        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: This is what I have in the txt file:[TabsInTxtFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cino5.png)
      and after running the above code this is the result in Excel:[ExcelResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hznu.png)

Comment: there's a `Split()` overload taking a `StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries`...but don't multiple tabs mean multiple columns...so multiple commas should actually be correct?

Comment: Multiple tabs means empty cells. You *don't* want to remove them. Why *replace* tabs with commas anyway? Any application that can read a CSV can handle tabs as a field delimiter. In fact, this avoids confusion with thousand/decimal separators in numeric fields. Just specify `\t` as the field separator in whatever library or code you use to process the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I used REGEX to replace multi-tab with a single tab

For example, with a input like this :

```
t       m   f           yf
```

The output after regex:

```
t   m   f   yf
```

**Code REGEX:**

```
    public string Format(string s)
    {
      string strRegex = @"[\t]+";
      Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
      string strReplace = @"[\t]";
      return myRegex.Replace(s, strReplace);
    }
```

Next, I do like you did, replace a tab by a ,

```
private void ConvertToCSV(ListBox listBox)
        {
            string txtpath = DIRPATH + listBoxFiles.SelectedItem + ".txt";
            string csvpath = DIRPATH + listBoxFiles.SelectedItem + ".csv";

            // Read through rows in the text file and replace tabs with 
            // commas

            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtpath);
            var csv = lines.Select(row => string.Join(",", Format(row).Split('\t')));

            // Replace the .txt extention with .csv

            File.WriteAllLines(txtpath, csv);
            System.IO.File.Move(txtpath, csvpath);

            }
```

Comment: `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` is a better choice (we have no need in array; `IEnumerable<string>` will be enough)

Comment: I tried your initial solution but got stuck with /t where my commas should be so I just made a simple change in the Format Method. This I guess could render my replacement line useless besides the by the row reading functionality. Thanks!